# PHP MySQL set selected selectpicker multiple

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, select

i need help for my php script with bootstrap selectpicker integration

i have php script for show selectpicker multiple value

```
<select id="skill" name="skill" class="selectpicker" multiple data-size="5" data-selected-text-format="count">
<?php
$skills = mysql_query("SELECT skill_id, skill_name FROM skill",$conn);
while($r_skills = mysql_fetch_assoc($skills)){
echo '<option value="'.$r_skills['skill_id'].'">'.$r_skills['skill_name'].'</option>
';
}
?>  
</select>
```

and on my other table i have user and skill_id, for skill_id content : 1, 2, 3

i had explode it into each value like this :

```
$q = ("SELECT nik, skill_id FROM dosen WHERE nik = '".$nik."'",$conn);
while($row_dosen = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){

$pieces = explode(",", $row_dosen['skill_id']);

for($i = 0; $i < count($pieces) ; $i++){

$pp  = mysql_query("SELECT skill_id, skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id = '".$pieces[$i]."'",$conn);

while($p = mysql_fetch_assoc($pp)){
    $var_each = $p['skill_id']; 

}
}
}
```

The question is : how i can set default selected value for my multiple selectpicker option to make them selected as my user data on table ?

Thank you.
The help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
<select id="skill" name="skill" class="selectpicker" multiple data-size="5" data-selected-text-format="count">
<?php
    $skills = mysql_query("SELECT skill_id, skill_name FROM skill",$conn);
    while($r_skills = mysql_fetch_assoc($skills)){
      echo '<option value="'.$r_skills['skill_id'].'"';
      if ($r_skills['skill_id'] == '1337 codingz')
          echo ' selected';
      echo '>'.$r_skills['skill_name'].'</option>';
}
?>  
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback , but what's the meaning of 1337 codingz ? what about skill_id on dosen table? :)

Comment: Sorry,`'1337 codingz'` was used as a place holder for the skill for the user.  You would need to fill in the user's skill with the results of some query on your user table, or a default value.